# Implementing Facebook Connect on Subdomains

Tags: php, facebook, subdomain

How do I keep my applications settings on Facebook, so that it supports subdomains?

I just integrated a question and answer type forum on a school community and its available at http://swades.engr.scu.edu/askswades/

Thus here were my settings on Facebook :

```
Site URL : http://swades.engr.scu.edu/
Site Domain : scu.edu
```

I am not able to get it working this way. What am I doing wrong? I double checked the API settings on code, and its all right.

Will be great if someone can help me! Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

This is setup correctly and should be working. Without seeing errors, its hard to know what's broken.

As long as you only implement Facebook Authentication on URLs which are a subdomains of your Site Domain, all is well. The Site URL is for linking purposes, it does not tie FB Auth to that URL.

You can check Auth is working by calling FB.login() in JS in any page which is being served on a subdomain of scu.edu: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/

Answer (score 0):

Facebook says that all subdomains will work, but you can try adding swades.engr.scu.edu also to your list of domains.